# How do I change the integer axis labels on a seaborn chart to my own strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mapping, seaborn, axis-labels

Because seaborn violins only use numbers, he turned intentional votes into whole numbers. Will it be possible to put the right labels on them?

I did

```
def code(x):
    if x == (df['Intention_vote_2021'][0]):
        return 0
    elif x == (df['Intention_vote_2021'][1]):
        return 1
    elif x == (df['Intention_vote_2021'][2]):
        return 2
    elif x == (df['Intention_vote_2021'][3]):
        return 3

df['ascii'] = [code(x) for x in df['Intention_vote_2021']] # crecion de una nueva columna objetivo

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,8)
plt.rcParams["axes.titlesize"] = 18
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 16
plt.rcParams["xtick.labelsize"] = 12
plt.rcParams["ytick.labelsize"] = 12

# Create violinplot
plt.subplot(121)
v1 = sns.violinplot(x = "Groupe_dage", y="ascii", data=df)
v1.axes.set_title("Voting intention according to age", fontsize=20)

plt.subplot(122)
v2 = sns.violinplot(x = "Revenu_mensuel", y="ascii", data=df)
v2.axes.set_title("Voting intention according to income", fontsize=20)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

And it returned:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

And I'd like to use the actual labels that come from the data frame:

```
{ 0: df['Intention_vote_2021'][0],
  1: df['Intention_vote_2021'][1],
  2: df['Intention_vote_2021'][2],
  3: df['Intention_vote_2021'][3]
}
```

I tried to add `plt.yticks([0,1,2,3], df['Intention_vote_2021'])` after each `sns.violinplot()`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,8)
plt.rcParams["axes.titlesize"] = 18
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 16
plt.rcParams["xtick.labelsize"] = 12
plt.rcParams["ytick.labelsize"] = 12

# Create violinplot
plt.subplot(121)
v1 = sns.violinplot(x = "Groupe_dage", y="ascii", data=df)
plt.yticks([0,1,2,3], df['Intention_vote_2021'])
v1.axes.set_title("Voting intention according to age", fontsize=20)

plt.subplot(122)
v2 = sns.violinplot(x = "Revenu_mensuel", y="ascii", data=df)
plt.yticks([0,1,2,3], df['Intention_vote_2021'])
v2.axes.set_title("Voting intention according to income", fontsize=20)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

write

```
plt.yticks([0,1,2,3], df['Intention_vote_2021'])
```

after each of your `violinplot()`

Comment: Yeah ! It almost worked ! I don't know why one ticker appears twice and another one none.

Comment: Can you show an updated picture and the content of df[intention vote 2021]

Comment: Yes, sorry, just did